# postgres cannot select from huge table after imported

Tags: postgresql

I am imported my table using the following command:

```
sudo -u postgres psql enwiki -c "COPY public.categorylinks FROM '`pwd`/enwiki-latest-categorylinks.txt' WITH DELIMITER E'\t' CSV QUOTE '''' ESCAPE '\\' encoding 'latin1';"
```

I then ran a query to retrieve the table statistics:

```
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation",
pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "size" FROM pg_class C LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace) WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') ORDER BY pg_relation_size(C.oid) DESC LIMIT 20;
```

It gave me the following output:

```
public.categorylinks          | 8864 MB
public.cl_sortkey             | 8312 MB
public.cl_from                | 3963 MB
public.category_title         | 142 MB
public.category               | 137 MB
```

However, if I try to select from the categorylinks table, I do not receive any results.
Here is my output:

```
enwiki=# select count(*) from categorylinks;
count
-----
0

select * from categorylinks limit 1;
cl_from | cl_to | cl_sortkey | cl_timestamp | cl_sortkey_prefix | cl_collation | cl_type 
---------+-------+------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+---------
(0 rows)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance at all of connecting to the database with pgAdmin?

Comment: When this happened to me in the past, it was the result of large failed transactions, and `VACUUM` recovered the storage.

Comment: Did the `copy` succeed without error? If you `cluster` or `vacuum full` the tables (this may take a while) do they stay big, or suddenly become tiny on disk?

Comment: I believe the copy command succeeded without error. After I ran the select command, I viewed all running queries and there is a vacuum on the categorylinks table that has been running for over a day. This may be why the count(*) returned 0 rows. I do not know why the vacuum query is taking so long or how to stop it. select * from pg_stat_activity; autovacuum: VACUUM public.categorylinks

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes for problems like this include:

1)  Having created the table in one transaction, copied it in another and then, if you neglect to commit, you try to select in another session.  In fact I had something like this happen today :-P

2)  The copy succeeds, something later in the transaction fails, causing all the rows to disappear on rollback.

Because of the way PostgreSQL stores data, these are pretty routine cases and explain virtually all such row disappearances.  Both are behavior by design and are resolved by making sure the transaction that inserted the rows commits properly and without other errors.